# Launch new Activity from FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, overlay

I try to study overlay library for kotlin applications https://github.com/KoderLabs/overlay-service. Right now I have a problem related with opening a new activity from a button which is located inside a `FrameLayout` class.
So, the task is push on button on Main Activity -> open new overlay small window and roll up Main Activity -> push on button inside a small window -> open new Activity.
In this code nothing happens after the clicking on button.
The project include main 3 classes:

1. MainActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    btn_simple_pip.setOnClickListener {
        checkDrawOverlayPermission(IMPLEMENTED_PIP_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE)
        finishAffinity()
    }

}

private fun checkDrawOverlayPermission(code: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
            startActivityForResult(intent, IMPLEMENTED_PIP_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            openFloatingWindow(code)
        }
    } else {
        openFloatingWindow(code)
    }
}

private fun openFloatingWindow(code: Int) {
    when (code) {
        IMPLEMENTED_PIP_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, ImplementPipOverlayService::class.java)
            val videoUrl =
                "https://s3.amazonaws.com/data.development.momentpin.com/2019/7/3/1562152168485485-0661a550-9d83-11e9-9028-d7af09cf782e.mp4"
            val notificationTitle = "Pip Overlay"
            val notificationDescription = "Pip overlay description"
            val notificationIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground
            val closeBtnColor = android.R.color.black
            val closeBtnBgColor = android.R.color.transparent
            intent.putExtra(ImplementPipOverlayService.KEY_STRING_VIDEO_URL, videoUrl)
            intent.putExtra(ImplementPipOverlayService.KEY_STRING_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTION, notificationDescription)
            intent.putExtra(ImplementPipOverlayService.KEY_STRING_NOTIFICATION_TITLE, notificationTitle)
            intent.putExtra(ImplementPipOverlayService.KEY_INT_NOTIFICATION_ICON, notificationIcon)
            intent.putExtra(ImplementPipOverlayService.KEY_INT_CLOSE_BUTTON_COLOR, closeBtnColor)
            intent.putExtra(ImplementPipOverlayService.KEY_INT_CLOSE_BUTTON_BG_COLOR, closeBtnBgColor)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, intent)
        }
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        IMPLEMENTED_PIP_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE, RESIZEABLE_CUSTOM_WEB_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE,
        PIP_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE, RESIZEABLE_CUSTOM_VIDEO_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    openFloatingWindow(requestCode)
                }
            } else {
                openFloatingWindow(requestCode)
            }
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}

companion object {
    const val IMPLEMENTED_PIP_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE = 251
    const val PIP_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE = 252
    const val RESIZEABLE_CUSTOM_VIDEO_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE = 253
    const val RESIZEABLE_CUSTOM_WEB_OVERLAY_REQUEST_CODE = 254
}
```

2. ImplementPipOverlayService

   ```
   class ImplementPipOverlayService : PipOverlayService() {

   var videoUrl: String? = null
   var notificationTitle: String? = null
   var notificationDescription: String? = null
   var notificationIcon: Int? = null
   var closeButtonColor: Int? = null
   var closeButtonBg: Int? = null

   override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
       videoUrl = intent?.getStringExtra(KEY_STRING_VIDEO_URL)
       notificationTitle = intent?.getStringExtra(KEY_STRING_NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
       notificationDescription = intent?.getStringExtra(KEY_STRING_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTION)
       notificationIcon = intent?.getIntExtra(KEY_INT_NOTIFICATION_ICON, -1)
       closeButtonColor = intent?.getIntExtra(KEY_INT_CLOSE_BUTTON_COLOR, -1)
       closeButtonBg = intent?.getIntExtra(KEY_INT_CLOSE_BUTTON_BG_COLOR, -1)
       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
   }

   override fun getForegroundNotification(): Notification {
       val channelId =
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                   createNotificationChannel("my_service", "My Background Service")
               } else {
                   packageName
               }
       var notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)

       notificationBuilder = notificationTitle?.let {
           notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(it)
       } ?: run {
           notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title")
       }
       notificationDescription?.let {
           notificationBuilder = notificationBuilder.setContentText(it)
       }
       notificationIcon?.let {
           notificationBuilder = notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(it)
       }

       val notification: Notification = notificationBuilder.build()
       return notification
   }

   @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
   private fun createNotificationChannel(channelId: String, channelName: String): String {
       val chan = NotificationChannel(channelId,
               channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE)
       chan.lightColor = Color.BLUE
       chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
       val service = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
       service.createNotificationChannel(chan)
       return channelId
   }

   override fun getInitialWindowSize(): Point {
       return Point(100.toDp(), 100.toDp())
   }

   override fun getCustomLayoutId(): Int {
       return R.layout.pip_layout
   }

   override fun onServiceRun() {
       setOnEventListener(onFullscreen = {
           // Not implemented
       }, onClosed = {
           // Not implemented
       })

       pipView.removeFullscreenButton()

       closeButtonColor?.let {
           pipView.getCloseButton().setColorFilter(it)
       }

       closeButtonBg?.let {
           pipView.getCloseButton().setBackgroundColor(it)
       }

   }


   companion object {
       const val KEY_STRING_VIDEO_URL = "video_url"
       const val KEY_INT_CLOSE_BUTTON_COLOR = "close_button_color"
       const val KEY_INT_CLOSE_BUTTON_BG_COLOR = "close_button_background"
       const val KEY_STRING_NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "notification_title"
       const val KEY_STRING_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTION = "notification_description"
       const val KEY_INT_NOTIFICATION_ICON = "notification_icon"
   }
   ```
3. OverlayPipCustomView

class OverlayPipCustomView : FrameLayout {
private lateinit var constraintsRoot: ConstraintLayout
private lateinit var imageFullscreenButton: ImageView
private lateinit var imageCloseButton: ImageView
private lateinit var customLayoutContent: FrameLayout
private lateinit var customView: View
private lateinit var touchView: View
private lateinit var button: Button

```
private var playerViewSize: Int = 0
private var sizeChangeable: Boolean = true
private var playerType: Int = 0

private var haveFullscreen = true
/**
 * Tracks if viewResizeable is fullscreen.
 */
private var fullscreenOn: Boolean = false
val isDraggable: Boolean
    get() {
        return !fullscreenOn
    }

private var onFullscreen: () -> Unit = {}
private var onClosed: () -> Unit = {}

private var canHideActionButtons = true
private val hideActionHandler = Handler()
private val HIDE_ACTION_DURATION = 2000L
private val hideActionRunnable = Runnable {
    if (!isMoving) {
        hideActions()
    }
}

var isMoving: Boolean = false

constructor(ctx: Context) : super(ctx) {
    inflate(context, R.layout.layout_pip_custom_view, this)
    initView()
}

constructor(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(ctx, attrs) {
    setAttributes(attrs)
    inflate(context, R.layout.layout_pip_custom_view, this)
    initView()
}

constructor(ctx: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(ctx, attrs, defStyle) {
    setAttributes(attrs)
    inflate(context, R.layout.layout_pip_custom_view, this)
    initView()
}

private fun setAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet) {
    context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.OverlayCustomView,
            0, 0).apply {
        try {
            playerViewSize = getInteger(R.styleable.OverlayCustomView_ov_player_size, 0)
            playerType = getInteger(R.styleable.OverlayCustomView_ov_size_changeable, 0)
            sizeChangeable = getBoolean(R.styleable.OverlayCustomView_ov_size_changeable, true)
        } finally {
            recycle()
        }
    }

    doOnLayout {
        startHideAction()
    }
}

private fun initView() {
    button = findViewById(R.id.button)
    constraintsRoot = findViewById(R.id.constraints_root)
    imageFullscreenButton = findViewById(R.id.image_screen_action)
    imageCloseButton = findViewById(R.id.image_close)
    customLayoutContent = findViewById(R.id.custom_view)
    touchView = findViewById(R.id.touch_view)

    setListeners()
}

fun addCustomView(view: View) {
    customLayoutContent.addView(view)
}

fun addCustomView(layoutId: Int) {
    customView = inflate(context, layoutId, null)
    customLayoutContent.addView(customView)
}

fun getCloseButton() = imageCloseButton
fun getConstraintsRoot() = constraintsRoot
fun getCustomLayoutContent() = customLayoutContent
fun getCustomView() = customView
fun getFullscreenButton() = imageFullscreenButton
fun getTouchView() = touchView

fun removeFullscreenButton() {
    haveFullscreen = false
    imageFullscreenButton.invisible()
}


private fun setListeners() {
    imageFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener {
        onFullscreen.invoke()
    }

    button.setOnClickListener{
        println("pressed")
        fun alert(context: Context, text: String) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity2::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("text", text)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }


    imageCloseButton.setOnClickListener {
        onClosed.invoke()
    }
}

fun setOnEventActionListener(
        onFullscreen: () -> Unit,
        onClosed: () -> Unit
) {
    this.onFullscreen = onFullscreen
    this.onClosed = onClosed
}

private fun startHideAction() {
    if (canHideActionButtons) {
        hideActionHandler.postDelayed(hideActionRunnable, HIDE_ACTION_DURATION)
    }
}

fun restartHideAction() {
    hideActionHandler.removeCallbacks(hideActionRunnable)
    if (canHideActionButtons) {
        hideActionHandler.postDelayed(hideActionRunnable, HIDE_ACTION_DURATION)
    }
}

fun hideActions() {
    if (canHideActionButtons) {
        imageCloseButton.invisible()
        if (haveFullscreen) {
            imageFullscreenButton.invisible()
        }
    }
}

fun showActions() {
    imageCloseButton.visible()
    if (haveFullscreen) {
        imageFullscreenButton.visible()
    }
}
```

}

In third class I can't understand what should be placed here to to change initial first Activity to another one

```
    button.setOnClickListener{
        println("pressed")
        fun alert(context: Context, text: String) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity2::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("text", text)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`startService(intent)` will try and start a new `Service` and unfortunately does not throw an error if you call it with an `Activity` class.

To launch `MainActivity2` instead call `context.startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: Fixed. Still doesn't work. But thank you for answer!